# How to share the data from Parent Component to Multiple Child components in Angular?

Tags: angular

How  to share the data from Parent Component  to Multiple Child components  in Angular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Subject and subscribe to it from multiple components.

**Parent Component**

```
constructor(private event:serviceFile){}
eventSubscriber:Subscription|any;
data:any;    //<- data that you want to send to child component
ngOnInit(){
  this.event.sendDataToChildComponent(data);  //<- Function inside service
}
```

**ServiceFile**

```
subjectName = new Subject<any>();
sendDataToChildComponent(data:any){
    this.subjectName(data).next();
}
```

**Child Component**

```
constructor(private event:serviceFile){}
eventSubscriber:Subscription|any;
ngOnInit(){
   this.event.subjectName.subscribe((data:any)=>{
       console.log(data)
   }
}
ngOnDestroy(){
     if(this.eventSubscriber)this.eventSubscriber.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service use that service to share the data with any component you like or a better approach will be to use @Input() in you child components to receive data from its parent component

Answer (score 0):

All child components get their data from parent through @Input decorator. Declaring a variable with the decorator in the child allows you to pass values from parent in the HTML template.

You can find more about it in the doc:
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

And also you could send data back to parent through @Output decorator (events).